# How to improve the performance of huge data Angular Material applications in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, internet-explorer-11, angular-material

We are developing an Angular Material application which has huge data — about 20 to 40 thousand rows. This kind of large applications works well in Chrome but in MSIE 11 and Edge, its performance is very slow.

Comment: 40,000 rows of data in a browser window??  This seems excessive, and completely unusable by a human.  Are you using *any* sort of paging, sorting, filtering, or just throwing more rows of data on the screen than humanly possible to look at?

Comment: Your question is both vague and broad: your first step is to diagnose your problem and hone in on the bottleneck -- this should be your actual question. Listing symptoms without context isn't going to yield much on Stackoverflow.

Comment: yeah, sounds like a job for pagination. have the user request the next page, and next set of rows. 40k all at once is bad for ui/ux.

Comment: Yes we are not showing the data using virtual repeat .But the actual problem We could not achieve the application speed in Internet Explorer11

Answer (score 1):

Virtualization should help, check something like https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat or

https://github.com/2fdevs/angular-virtual-list or

https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat

etc.

In my projects angular works well with 100 000 rows with virtualization

Also try to prevent deep nested of directive if you are using angular 1.x

Also try to not use watchers